# regex expression if then else

Tags: regex

There are 4 variables in a text string:

```
aaa
aaa HQ
bbb
bbb HQ
```

I need to find aaa & bbb in the string. However: if aaa HQ or bbb HQ are available I want to select those and disregard the non HQ versions.

```
Example text block:
aaa
aaa HQ
bbb
```

In this example the script should select aaa HQ (disregard aaa because an HQ is available) and bbb (because bbb hq is not available)
I made several tests but unsuccessfully.

This is my last attempt but it doesn't work if I delete the hq in the text string:

```
(?(?=aaa|bbb)(aaa|bbb)(?=.*hq)|(aaa|bbb))
```

linked here: https://regex101.com/r/GRs3RR/6

Comment: You may approach the problem from another perspective: match all with `aaa` and `bbb` strings with an optional space + `HQ`, say, with `(aaa|bbb)( +hq)?` pattern, and then check in the code if the space+HQ matched.

Comment: Can complete lines as in the example be assumed? I.e. are you looking for explicitly `aaa` or  `aaa HQ` alone on a line? Asking to clarify the possibility to use anchors like `^$`.

Comment: Why do you want to use regex for this? Current question can be done with simple string matching, and discarding `aaa` if `aaa HQ` is found.